# Why I can't set duration when hover over

Tags: html, css

I have transform scale on image, and set on hover duration 5s, but when I move mouse from image my image don'thave ease out duration of 5s , i think you understand me.

http://jsfiddle.net/oqa88vdo/
HTML

```
<img src="http://spmhire.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/rolls-royce.jpg">
```

CSS

```
img{
 width:150px

}
img:hover{
     transform: scale(2,3);
     transition: transform 1500ms ease;
}
```

i tried to set 
transition: 500ms ease-out 1s; but not working

Comment: What browser are you using? When I run your JSfiddle it works for me on newest Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the transition to the element itself, rather than the :hover psuedo-class:

```
img {
   width:150px;
   transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
}

img:hover{
     transform: scale(2,3);
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/oqa88vdo/3/

The reasoning behind this is that CSS transitions define how changes to the element will be applied going forward. You first set the transition behavior on the element, *then* any CSS that changes will use that transition behaviour.

The [developer guides at Mozilla cover this very well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions), it's worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the parameters in the non hover style as well, like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/oqa88vdo/

```css
img{
   width:150px;
   transform: scale(1,1); 
    transition:transform 1500ms ease;
        
}
img:hover{
     transform: scale(2,3);
     transition: transform 1500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://spmhire.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/rolls-royce.jpg">
```